# Strange behavior of confirmation in Telrik ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, dopostback, telerik-scheduler

**somePage.aspx**

```
<asp:LinkButton Runat="server" ID="butDelete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="Confirmation();return flag;"><img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" title='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:ClarityResources, resDelete %>" />'></asp:LinkButton>
```

**ClientSideCode.js**

```
 function confirmCallBackFn(sender) {
             debugger;
             if (sender)
                 flag = true;
             else
                 flag = false;
             return flag;
         }
         function Confirmation(sender,args) {
             debugger;
             radconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?',  confirmCallBackFn);
         }
```

but the on click always returns **false** which is default value set for the flag variable 
When i did debugging i seen that the on client click the  method confirmation gets called and it returns the default value false to the control and after clicking on the confirmation box's **Yes** or **cancel** it again runs the call back method **confirmCallBackFn(sender)** seperatly which returns flag but not in  same thread but in different thread. I tried different ways to solve it but i am stuck . so any help would be great .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to treat the radconfirm in the same way as a plain javascript confirm(), this isn't done in a like-for-like manner. I'll start with the Confirmation function.

```
function Confirmation(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    // The line below will open a rad confirmation window, it will not wait for the response
    radconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?', confirmCallBackFn);
}
```

To ensure that it doesn't automatically post back the above function should be changed as follows:

```
function Confirmation(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    // This line will open a rad confirmation window, it will not wait for the response
    radconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?', confirmCallBackFn);
    // The line below will prevent the control from automatically posting back
    return false;
}
```

The next step is correcting the call back function; The parameter passed into the function, as can be seen from the code rather than the parameter name is the boolean representation of the result from the confirmation box.

```
function confirmCallBackFn(sender) {
    debugger;
    if (sender)
        flag = true;
    else
        flag = false;
    return flag;
}
```

The previously written function returns a value, but this isn't used anywhere. The following code will perform the required action

```
function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
    debugger;
    if (arg) {
        // The line below will perform a post back, you might want to trigger this a different way
        __doPostBack(sender.id, "");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately as the sender is not passed into the callback function it is necessary to declare the function within the other JavaScript function as follows:

```
function Confirmation(sender) {
    debugger;
    // The callback function
    function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
        debugger;
        if (arg) {
            // Triggers postback only when confirmation box returns true
            __doPostBack(sender.id, "");
        }
    }
    // This line will open a rad confirmation window, it will not wait for the response
    radconfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?', confirmCallBackFn);
    return false;
}
```

You might find the following link useful in regards to using the radconfirm in the same way as a confirm:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/confirmserverclicks/defaultcs.aspx.

Comment: @talenga but the event we are calling is for the LinkButton. So does it also pass the sender and arguments list to the Confirmation function

Comment: You can pass the element by updating the call to Confirmation() on your OnClientClick event to use "Confirmation(this)" which will pass in the link button.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I alert user to confirm the delete event !

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"
  OnClick="btnDelete_clicked" OnClientClicking="RadConfirm" Width="100px">
    </telerik:RadButton>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function RadConfirm(sender, args) {
        var callBackFunction = Function.createDelegate(sender, function (shouldSubmit) {
            if (shouldSubmit) {
                this.click();
            }
        });
        var text = "Are you sure you want delete ?";
        radconfirm(text, callBackFunction, 300, 100, null, "Confirm Apply !");
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
</script>

     protected void btnDelete_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Write your server-side delete code here 
    }
```

Comment: For a demo from Telerik (similar to this answer) see: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/confirm/defaultcs.aspx