# How to Postback with radconfirm window with RadContextMenu?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have the code as below ,
For ASPX-->

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu ID="RadContextMenu1" runat="server" OnClientItemClicking="onClientContextMenuItemClicking" 
        OnItemClick="RadContextMenu1_ItemClick" OnInit="RadContextMenu1_OnInit"> 
        <Items> 
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Value="AddNick" Text="" /> 
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Value="Edit" Text="" /> 
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Value="Delete" Text="" Font-Bold="true" /> 
        </Items> 
    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
```

Javascript -->

```
 var allowPosback = false; 
 function confirmCallBackFn(arg, eventArgs) { 
                if (arg) { 
                    allowPosback = true; 
                } 
  } 

  function onClientContextMenuItemClicking(sender, eventArgs) { 
                var item = eventArgs.get_item(); 
                item.get_menu().hide(); 

                switch (item.get_value()) { 
                    case "Delete": 

                        var message = "Delete"
                        var event = "event"; 
                        var width = 300; 
                        var height = 100; 
                        var title = "Want To Delete";
                        radconfirm(message, confirmCallBackFn, width, height, null, title); 
                        eventArgs.set_cancel(allowPosback); 
                        break; 
                } 
            }
```

control is RadContextMenu not postback after confirm clicking why it is not having post back. Any help would be great ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how the radconfirm box works. I've recently answered a similar question ([Strange behavior of confirmation in Telrik ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372487/strange-behavior-of-confirmation-in-telrik/18381438#18381438)) which should help you re-write the code above to work properly.

Also you might find the following link useful (also posted at end of other answer): http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/confirmserverclicks/defaultcs.aspx.